# Google Places API в автокомплите не возвращает результатов при запросе на русском

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании Google Places API для Android
При попытке получить подсказки и указывая при этом в запросе например "Пушкинская", в ответ приходит пустой список.

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, query, null, null)
```

При этом с запросами на английском языке таких проблем нет.

Comment: попробуйте УРЛЕнкодить запрос

Comment: @metalurgus Не помогло